# cannot install VBoxGuestAdditions on debian 9 with vagrant

Tags: vagrant, debian, virtualbox

I cannot install VBoxGuestAdditions. 
I tried both with the [vagrant plugin](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) and manually. In both cases I encountered this error :

```
vboxadd.sh: Building Guest Additions kernel modules.
Failed to set up service vboxadd, please check the log file
/var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log for details.
```

`cat /var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log`:

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxadd.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxadd.service.
vboxadd.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong.
vboxadd.sh: failed: Please check that you have gcc, make, the header files for your Linux kernel and possibly perl installed..
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxadd-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxadd-service.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxadd-x11.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxadd-x11.service.
```

`cat  /var/log/vboxadd-install.log`

```
grep: /lib/modules/4.9.0-4-amd64/build/include/linux/version.h: No such file or directory
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/4.9.0-4-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 -j2 modules
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-4-amd64 KBUILD_SRC=/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-4-common \
-f /usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-4-common/Makefile modules
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
```

The following package is installed:

```
apt-get install build-essential dkms
```

How to fix that?